# Routing with open street maps

Tags: java, routes, openstreetmap

i have to develop a routing system with open street maps for my second year project (part of the project). I cannot use any external API's for routing. I understand .osm files and I was able to convert them to postgresql format using osm2po and create a database out of it but after this I am clueless. I have researched alot but cannot find any proper help on this topic. Any advice will be awesome.

Comment: May be, try posting this question on [Programmers Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).   Or [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) site. Here it's out of scope.

Comment: There have been many osm questions posted on this site so i thought i should ask 1 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just focussing on developping an new algorithm, you might have a look at the [Trafficmining framework](http://code.google.com/p/trafficmining/) that does all the parsing etc. for you and you just need to code the nessesary java components for your custom behaviour.

Comment: Thanks brother, I will have a look at it again. :)

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind that using OSM is a bit tricky as the data aren't 100% homogenous. If you need more ideas have a look at  
* http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Research  
* https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Conferences (Talks)

Comment: Yeah I can figure that out. Being a second year making a routing engine on our own is way too much brother.

Comment: Well indeed it's a very good practical training (A* and graph funamentals, big data, real world example, ...) but usually students lack of time to enjoy this experience and get a real satisfying result :)  

So try to splitup the task (parsing OSM, data model, routing on model) and to focus on that part that the exercise requires.

Comment: Thats what I an confused about, How can I change my database data to a graph. Its so complicated for me.

Comment: There is no easy way to do so. In general you construct a graph by using only crossings of 2 ways that suitable for your routing and connect them with a edge. But you need to take a lot of tagging aspects into account to get useful results. This is what Trafficmining and osm2pgrouting are doing for you, so you can work on the graph and need only to tweak the A* params

Comment: I may be sounding like a noob, but what I have got using osmpo looks like this - : http://prntscr.com/2tymxf
 I cannot see anything like ways on it. All i can see is x1, y1 which are the lat and long of source point and x2 y2 which are the lat lon of source code.

Comment: I'm not experienced with this osm2po thing, but it looks like an regular pgrouting table: http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/tutorial/topology.html#topology

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really tell us where you are stuck. But I suggest starting to read the OSM wiki about [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) and [tags for routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_tags_for_routing). Looking at one of the many [online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) and [offline routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers) for OSM will get you some ideas, too.

Comment: I have got the sql table having columns like x1 y1 x2 y2 but i really don't know what they stand for and how can I use them in Hjikstra's or A* algorithm to find the shortest route between two points.

Comment: I guess first you have to build a graph from all the elements in your DB while taking the [tags for routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_tags_for_routing) into account.

Comment: Thanks I am now able to use the database to plot points on the map on streets. I will now concentrate other aspects of my project and then will start to implement Dikstra algorithm on the database.